# Button não Centraliza com imagem

Tags: html5, css3

**Meu Button não está centralizando ao meio da imagem na versão desktop. na versão mobile alinha conforme o tamanho da tela..**

```
@media ( max-width: 800px ) { #btn-primary{
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Rye', coursive;
  background-color: #000;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
}
#btn-primary{
  font-family: 'Rye', coursive;
  background-color: #000;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="section mt-5" id="tattoo">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>TATTOO</h2>
            <p>Fazemos todos os estilos de tatuagem.</p>
            <img src="fig1.svg">
            <img src="fig2.svg">
        </div>
        <a id="btn-primary" class="btn btn-primary" href="galeria.html" role="button">GALERIA</a>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Ja tentou subir a tag a pra dentro da div com classe container ?
e adiciona uma classe pra ele com margin: 0 auto;

Daí você pode passar outra classe e estiliza ela no CSS passando display: flex; flex-direction: column; ficando algo assim no HTML:

```
<div class="container outraClasse">
    <div class="imagesContainer>
      <img1 src="..." alt="..."/>
      <img2 src="..." alt="..." />
    </div>
    <a id="btn-primary" class="btn btn-primary botao" href="galeria.html" role="button">GALERIA</a>
</div>
```

e no CSS:

```
.outraClasse { display: flex; flex-direction:column;}
.imagesContainer { display: flex;}
.botao { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: tentei aqui, porém, o button vai para o lado da imagem não ficando inferior conforme o exemplo que coloquei